# Objective C : Class method declaration error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

### UPDATE

It turns out that I was calling a class method on an instance of that class.

I've fixed that line of code to be:

```
double result = [CalculatorBrain runProgram:[self.brain program] usingVariableValues:[self variableValues]];
```

But when I run the program and that line is evaluated, I get the following error:

**+[CalculatorBrain runProgram:usingVariableValues:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x6908**

### ORIGINAL

Why am I getting the following error in XCode inside of the view's enterPressed: *No visible @interface for 'CalculatorBrain' declares the selector 'runProgram:usingVariableValues:'* ?

### ** CalculatorViewController.m **

```
#import "CalculatorViewController.h"
#import "CalculatorBrain.h"

@interface CalculatorViewController()

@property (nonatomic, strong) CalculatorBrain *brain;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *variableValues;

@end

@implementation CalculatorViewController

@synthesize brain = _brain;
@synthesize variableValues = _variableValues;

- (CalculatorBrain *)brain {
    if (!_brain) _brain = [[CalculatorBrain alloc] init];
    return _brain;
}

- (NSMutableDictionary *)variableValues {
    if (!_variableValues) {
        _variableValues = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    }
    return _variableValues;
}

- (IBAction)enterPressed {

    double *result = [self.brain runProgram:[self.brain program] usingVariableValues:[self variableValues]];

}
```

### ** CalculatorBrain.h **

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CalculatorBrain : NSObject

+ (double)runProgram:(id)program usingVariableValues:(NSDictionary *)variableValues;

@property (readonly) id program;


@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CalculatorBrain.h, you're declaring a class method instead of an  instance method:

```
+ (double)runProgram:(id)program usingVariableValues:(NSDictionary *)variableValues;
```

Use `-` instead of `+`.

Or, if you intend this to be a class method, call it as such:

```
 double *result = [CalculatorBrain runProgram:[self.brain program] usingVariableValues:[self variableValues]];
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was meaning to use it as a class method.

Comment: When I try the second line of code, I see the following error:

    _Initializing 'double *' with an expression of incompatible type 'double';_

Comment: Use `double result =` without the *.

Comment: Thanks, Darren, that works. Why?

Although, I get an error when running the code and having that line of code fire: _+[CalculatorBrain runProgram:usingVariableValues:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x6908
(lldb)_

Comment: It works because the return type of `+[CalculatorBrain runProgram:usingVariableValues:]` is `double` not "pointer to `double`", i.e. `double *`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding a class level method, then you aren't calling the method on the instance - but on the class itself.  For example:

```
double *result = [self.brain runProgram:[self.brain program] usingVariableValues:[self variableValues]];
```

Would become:

```
double *result = [CalculatorBrain runProgram:[self.brain program] usingVariableValues:[self variableValues]];
```

I don't see the method defined above, so I can't be sure if that is what you are intending.

Comment: Thank you, I missed that I was calling the method on my class' instance rather than on the class itself.

The line of code you provided gives an error, however, and must not use a pointer on the double. I'm not sure why. This works:

    double result = [CalculatorBrain runProgram:program usingVariableValues:[self variableValues]];

Comment: UPDATE: Xcode does not show an error, but I do get an error when I run the code

    unrecognized selector sent to class 0x6908